# Top conferences about natural language process

Tags: nlp

What's the top conferences of the Natural Language Procss field?
And what's the hottest topics of the field?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the biggest conferences:

- [ACL](http://www.acl2012.org/)
- [EMNLP](http://emnlp-conll2012.unige.ch/)
- [NAACL](http://www.naaclhlt2012.org/)
- [EACL](http://www.eacl.org/)
- [COLING](http://www.coling2012-iitb.org/)

You can find lists of hot topics in the "call for papers" of any conference.  For example: [here](http://emnlp-conll2012.unige.ch/call.html).